# Increase Kubernetes Nginx Ingress limits for large images in Docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm, ingress, docker-registry

When pushing images to a self hosted [Docker registry installed using their official helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry), this works for some images. But for one image, I'm not able to push two layers. Docker retry it several times, without success.

```
3a6fab8d5d23: Retrying in 2 seconds
```

The logs of the Kubernetes pod gave me the following error:

```
unknown error reading request payload: unexpected EOF
```

Both layers were relatively large (252.5 MB/ 393.8 MB).

#### What I already tried on the Ingress

I had the Kubernetes Nginx Ingress behind my registy. Using the direct `NodePort` without Ingress, it works perfectly. So it seems that some limits of the Ingress break the upload. The following annotations were applied:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts: 
    - my-docker-registry.domain
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my-docker-registry.domain
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "900"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "900"
```

This was taken from [the Nginx Ingress documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/docker-registry/ingress-without-tls.yaml), where a Docker Registry behind Nginx acts as example. Are there any other limits I need to increase so that my registry will properly work behind the Ingress?

#### Background

I want to install the [Component Pack for IBM Connections](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/install/cp_install_config_intro.html). IBM has a very special way to deliver this Kubernetes based application: You get a ~4GB Zip file. It contains all images and helm charts as well as a shell script, which tags and pushes all those images to a custom registry. The `cnx-ingress` image is relatively large:

```
:~/Downloads/IC-ComponentPack-6.0.0.8# l microservices_connections/hybridcloud/images/cnx-ingress.tar 
-rw------- 1 daniel daniel 739M Mär 29 13:18 microservices_connections/hybridcloud/images/cnx-ingress.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned that it's not required to set the ingress class to nginx as I did in `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`. All annotations prefixed with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` apply to the default Kubernetes ingress. Setting the timeouts is also not required. The only important annotation is

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
```

because the default value is way too small for Docker image layers. Without this annotation, we get `413 Request Entity Too Large` errors.

The main problem in my case was somewhere else: We had a HAProxy loadbalancer in front of our Kubernetes workers. Being new in those HA technology, it's configuration was pretty default. It contains the following directives:

```
defaults
    # ...
    retries 3
    timeout connect     1000
    timeout client      1000
    timeout server      1000
```

According to [HAProxys time formats](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#2.49), this got interpreted as ms. In our testing environment, I increased both client/server timeouts to 600s. This fixed all our pushing problems.